# How not to Get discovered on Google Play search

Tags: google-play, store

I want to put my app on google play store but not open to search. I just want to use play store link to give anyone I want. I don't want my app to be listed on any search on play store.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the Alpha/Beta program: [googleplay support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

In general it works as following:

- Create an App
- Log into the Developer Console and upload an APK. No need to publish it yet.
- Check out the ‘Beta’ tab now, which should show this handy message:

[image: beta tab]

- Using your developer account (it must be the primary google developer account), create a Google+ Community.
- Add your Community to the list of testers by clicking “Manage list of testers” and pasting the Community’s url.
- Click again on “Manage list of testers” and there you will find a URL to share with your Community.

Comment: I dont want to create a group. I just want to use the google play store link and published app but not searchable. Thank you for your answer.